# Execute Java jar via systemd service script Fedora 22

Tags: linux, fedora, systemd

I'm trying to create a service script for a Java application I have but I keep getting the below error. I've no idea what's going on because I've provided the absolute path in all areas possible.

```
07:57:17 executive systemd[1]: [/usr/lib/systemd/system/my_java_app.service:14] Missing '='. Aug 14 07:57:33 executive systemd[1]: [/usr/lib/systemd/system/my_java_app.service:7] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring:..._app.jar Aug 14
```

Here is my current service script with with absolute paths in place:

```
[Unit] Description=my_java_app

After=syslog.target After=network.target

[Service] 

ExecStart=/usr/java/jre1.8.0_45/bin/java -jar /opt/my_java_app.jar


Type=simple

Restart=on-failure

[Install] 

WantedBy=multi-user.target

EOFs
```

I'm no Linux expert so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly error on my behalf.

It was complaining about the EOF string at the end of the script. I thought this was needed by systemd service scripts but evidently it's not.

Very misleading error message but hopefully helps somebody else.